# JQuery Ajax loaded content unable to call PHP variables from parent

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have variable in the parent document eg.

```
$var = 'blah';
```

Then a div is populated with a Jquery AJAX call and that file has the line.

```
<?php echo $var; ?>
```

At the moment I am getting

```
Notice: Undefined variable:
```

How can I resolve this.

Comment: Can you explain better where are `$var = 'blah';`, `<?php echo $var; ?>` and where you get `Notice: Undefined variable:`? Specifying the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your $var in the same php as the jQuery? You need to echo the $var from the php file that you initialized it in.

For Example:

A.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "B.php",
                    success : function(out) {
                        $('#out').html(out);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="out">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

B.php

```
<?php
  $var = "foo";
  echo $var;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable defined on the parent page cannot be accessed by the page requested through your jQuery AJAX request because the AJAX request creates a separate HTTP request, meaning that the page has no link to your parent page and will not be able to access anything defined in it.

You could try sending the value of `$var` through the `data` parameter of the [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function, alternatively, just repopulate `$var` on the page you request through AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaScript (jQuery) is performed purely on the client side and an AJAX call is just a separate page request, there is no way for the calling script to be aware of the "parent" one. I suggest you pass the `$var` to the script via GET or POST.